# How to force Jest to output snapshots inside root lvl __snapshots__ folder?

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I came across small issue with jest today, my folder structure follows this convention

```
components/
   Paragraph/
     index.js
     style.js
     test.js
```

When I run jest snapshot tests it generates them inside each component folder i.e

```
components/
   Paragraph/
     __snapshots__
     index.js
     style.js
     test.js
```

Is there a way to force jest to put all snapshots inside root lvl `__snapshot__` folder? So final output looks more like this

```
__snapshots__
   // All snapshots here?
components/
   Paragraph/
     index.js
     style.js
     test.js
```

Comment: I don't see any option on CLI to change default snapshot path. Why do you need to change the folder ?

Comment: @Tobino Would clean up file tree a bit

Answer (score 2):

In **package.json** (or in jest.config.js, if you use) add path to snapshotResolver file

```
"jest": {
    "snapshotResolver": "./snapshotResolver.js"
}
```

In root project create snapshotResolver.js file with this code:

```
const path = require('path')

const rootDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..')

module.exports = {
  testPathForConsistencyCheck: 'some/__tests__/example.test.js',

  /** resolves from test to snapshot path */
  resolveSnapshotPath: (testPath, snapshotExtension) => {
    return testPath.replace('src/', '__snapshots__/') + snapshotExtension
  },

  /** resolves from snapshot to test path */
  resolveTestPath: (snapshotFilePath, snapshotExtension) => {
    return snapshotFilePath
      .replace('__snapshots__/', 'src/')
      .slice(0, -snapshotExtension.length)
  },
}
```

https://gist.github.com/prescottprue/5ece5e173bcfba7ed86dae6a91444451

Comment: should this be `return rootDir + testPath.replace('src/', '__snapshots__/') + snapshotExtension` ? rootDir isn't being used.

Comment: @wongz please answer in source https://gist.github.com/prescottprue/5ece5e173bcfba7ed86dae6a91444451